# what happens with the auto increment primary field when data is restored from a backup

Tags: mysql

My MySQL table is something like:

```
userid(AI,PRIMARY)    name    password
1                     aa       dfsdfsdfds
2                     ioi      kjkjkjkjk
(3) user deleted his account
4                     ghghj    jhjhkhj
```

and there is another table with there info

```
userid( will be userid from above table)    address    phone
1                                            sfdsfds   9999999
2                                            dfsdfdsf   333333
3 (deleted)
4                                            sdfdsf     999999
```

When I will backup and restore the data, what will happen what will be my table data of table 1?

Comment: How are you performing the backup & restore?

Comment: Did you actually try to backup and restore on another database? What happened?

Comment: It would be very broken (IMNSHO) if you are not able to insert a value of your choosing (such as a value from a backup) in an auto-increment column.  But surely, you can experiment with this and find the answer quicker than asking the question.  It isn't hard to create a simple table, put some data in it, back it up, restore it, and get on with life knowing the answer.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM? In InnoDB, you should probably create a foreign-key relationship between these tables (if you can't simply merge them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you export your data (i.e. using `mysqldump`), all your keys (and their value) are exported as they are. The backup basically looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
    userid INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
INSERT INTO TABLE yourtable ( userid, name, password )
VALUES 
(1, 'aa', 'dfsdfsdfds'),
(2, 'ioi', 'kjkjkjkjk'),
(4, 'ghghj', 'jhjhkhj')
```

As you see in the example:

- your keys are being fully backuped and restored
- MySQL remembers the last auto-increment value and returns to that value on the next `INSERT`. (the next user will get id `5`)

Comment: But, if you don't include the CREATE statements (because you just want to backup the data, not the structure), then it won't set the AUTO_INCREMENT. You'd have to set it on your own I guess. I ran into this and will be doing it that way because I didn't want to carry over the structure to a new system, and instead use fresh structure from my maintained model.